# Paging On Simple View Without Using Any Grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have a simple page that showing list of data dynamically . The thing i want to do is just to do paging . I am not using any grid . Simply Data is showing on Page . So How Could i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

Give [Tablepager](http://dev.mariusilie.net/content/table-pager) a try.

Answer (score 0):

if your data is in a list you could do something like this after getting your data.

```
viewModel = data.Skip((page - 1) * _itemsPerPage).Take(_itemsPerPage);
```

and then pass that data in.  the only thing missing is setting up a page parameter and adding previous/next links to the page

this code would obviously go into your controller.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly more complex solution - but [MvcPager](http://mvcpager.codeplex.com/) will do what you're after.